# Module acer-wmi blocks gamepad

Tags: debian, kernel-modules

OS Debian Jessie `uname -a
Linux Taomon 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.43-2+deb8u2 (2017-06-26) x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Notebook

```
dmidecode -t  1
# dmidecode 2.12
SMBIOS 2.5 present.

Handle 0x0001, DMI type 1, 27 bytes
System Information
    Manufacturer: Acer           
    Product Name: Aspire 7736                    
    Version: 0100           
    Serial Number: LXPJA0231102209DE42000        
    UUID: 34399FC0-6F14-11DF-BF16-AE2F22C409A5
    Wake-up Type: Power Switch
    SKU Number: Not Specified
    Family: Not Specified
```

When module acer-wmi is loaded my gamepad is unusable. In Xorg.0.log I found

```
[    32.403] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Acer BMA150 accelerometer (/dev/input/js0)
[    32.403] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    32.403] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
```

even as root I can't access the device-node /dev/input/js0

```
 Error opening joystick device "/dev/input/js0": Operation is not permitted
```

Is there a way to avoid this, without blacklist modul acer-wmi?

```
 modinfo acer-wmi | grep -F parm
parm:           mailled:Set initial state of Mail LED (int)
parm:           brightness:Set initial LCD backlight brightness (int)
parm:           threeg:Set initial state of 3G hardware (int)
parm:           force_series:Force a different laptop series (int)
parm:           ec_raw_mode:Enable EC raw mode (bool)
```

Installing kernel from Stretch is not possible, it will install a bunch of packages from stable. Sooner or later it will break [apt](https://pastebin.ca/3844983)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now it works as I will. I created 2 udev-rules. The 1. erase the device /dev/input/js0.

```
cat /etc/udev/rules.d/98-accelerometer.rules 
# joystick-fix
SUBSYSTEM=="input", ACTION=="remove", ATTRS{name}=="Acer BMA150 accelerometer", ATTRS{phys}=="wmi/input1", RUN+="/bin/rm  %E{DEVNAME}"
SUBSYSTEM=="input", ACTION=="add", ATTRS{name}=="Acer BMA150 accelerometer", ATTRS{phys}=="wmi/input1", RUN+="/bin/rm  %E{DEVNAME}"
```

Sadly, linux remember this device and my gamepad was /dev/input/js1 again.

The 2. creates a Symlink /dev/input/js0, so my emulator is no longer yammering.

```
cat /etc/udev/rules.d/99-joystick.rules 
#joystick-fix 2. part
ACTION=="add", KERNEL=="js[1-9]", SUBSYSTEM=="input", ATTRS{product}=="USB Joystick     ", SYMLINK+="input/js0"
```